# How to achieve full screen multi-layer dropdown menu like that implemented in nixon.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to implement the same full screen dropdown-menu like the one in www.nixon.com. But I cannot find any plugins in the internet. Does anyone know how it is built?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can have a div with the nav items and give it a height: 0 property and a transition to it. Then when the nav options are hovered on you can increase the height of the nav items. This is just an example of a basic implementation with a lot of bugs, many other implementations can be used.
I suggest that you stop looking for plug-ins and code it yourself!

Comment: Could you please provide me with some simple example codes? Thanks